# Constraint layout Layout Crashing : All Children of constraint layout should have ids to use constraint set

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

After updating to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0`

The constraint layout crashes saying:

> All children of constraint layout should have ids to use constraint
> set

I have set ids to all views even then it's crashing.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.clone(ConstraintSet.java:687) at com.zoho.notebook.views.SettingsViewNavBar.showNoteSettingsView(SettingsViewNavBar.java:594) at com.zoho.notebook.views.SettingsViewNavBar.onClick(SettingsViewNavBar.java:303)
```

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: Do you mind sharing a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: please, put your layout and the way you are using constraintSet, otherwise is hard to give you a solution to your problem.

Comment: please post layout file

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had the same bug in my code. I had ids for all the views in xml, but I was manually adding a view to the constraint layout(a Tooltip view) with

```
constraintParent.addView(childView)
```

and while the dynamically added view is still on the parent if the constraint layout is redrawn (app goes to bg and resumed) this exception was getting triggered.

I fixed it by generating a view id for the dynamic view like this

```
CustomViewChildView childView = new CustomViewChildView()
childView.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

and then adding it to the constraint layout.

Comment: not works for me, I'm not adding views dynamically and all child views had ids, but steel crashes with same error

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili Please double check your code. When ever I faced the error, it was either missing id in xml or while dynamically adding view(which could be invisible)

Comment: Just to clarify that you should use: `nameOfChildView.setId(View.generateViewId());` where you replace "nameOfChildView" with your "ChildView's" variable name.

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget to **give the ConstraintLayout an id** as well.

I forgot this and it crashed my code. This isn't really obvious from the error.

Answer (score 6):

I just figure out how to fix this problem. Notice that is you must declare all view on ConstrainLayout have set ids, check example below:

In case 1 it's working success.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
    ...>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgId"
        ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        ... />
```

In case 2 below not working.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
        ...>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgId"
            ... />
        <TextView
          // do not set ids
            ... />
```

I hope this it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error until I realized that I hadn't given ids to some of the child elements in the ConstraintLayout. So, make sure you do not forget to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
Don't forget to add ID to all child of contraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to add new View at `onGlobalLayout()` (after main Layout is finalized). All id's in Layout were correct, new dynamical View ID was set (with `setId()`). But fault `"All Children of constraint layout should have ids to use constraint set"` kept occuring.

When I moved adding `View` to `onCreate()` everything went smooth. I just needed to change logic however on how where to put new `View`, as position of other Views is not determined at `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the crash appeared after I used the `Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources` feature. This action deleted an ID from the `MotionScene` layout description, and the same ID was also removed from the corresponding `MotionLayout`.